# subprocess не выполняет команду

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(['cd', 'C:\\ProgramData', '&&', 'mkdir', 'boot'])
print output
```

Почему не работает?

Comment: Что значит не работает? Не выполняется скрипт? Не создается папка? Ничего не пишется в стандартный вывод (и что вы ожидали там увидеть для этой команды?) ?

Comment: Выбивает ошибку Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e2e4.py", line 2, in <module>
    output = subprocess.check_output(['cd', C:\\ProgramData', '&&', 'mkdir', 'boot'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2]

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Subprocess changing directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21407005/6166540)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в вызове параметр `shell=True`. Нужен, когда вызываются не реальные экзешники, а команды интерпретатора.

P.S. Насколько я понял, на Винде ничего не дает передача команд списком, просто пишите в вызове полную строку команды.

Comment: Тут стоит упомянуть про нежелательное использование [`shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)